# Using OpenGL, are the results dependent on hardware or drivers installed?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, computer-vision

I am using OpenGL occlusion for a render as instructed here:  (https://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/HTML/gpugems/gpugems_ch29.html)

I am running the same code on Jupyter (it uses "Cirrus Logic GD 5446" as a GPU, a 25 year old PCI graphics chip that is emulated on the VM architecturer JupyterHub) and on a local machine (with GeForce 840M).

The code works on both environments, however, there is a slight difference in number of pixels that are generated for each facet. The local execution is a bit more accurate and also runs over two time faster.

Is it possible to achieve similar performance and results on all machines or this is something not in our hands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OpenGL specification is very clear about reproducibility (Invariance):

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf Appendix A

Identical results are warrented only for identical sequence of operations on the same implementation. Change only one operation, or the implementations and results may vary.